# how can I count a cell with the right name and has a value stored?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to count the number of cells in the right column only is they have a value in the second column.
for example:

[image]

I want to check if the first coloumn is a "busses" and if the second coloumn has a value stored. if all 2 condition are met is should count that cell.
in this case we have 13 elements but only 6 are busses and only 5 of them have a value stored, so it should return 5.

Comment: Could we show your attempts?

Comment: I don't know which command to use but I want to count IF A:A is equals to busses and case is not empty. but I don't know how to do that in excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `COUNTIFS` function. Insert the following formula:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$13,A1,$B$1:$B$13,"<>" )
```

[image: First formula]

Optionally, insert on the cell below it the formula below:

=IF(A2=A1,"",COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$13,A2,$B$1:$B$13,"<>"&""))

[image: Second formula]

Drag down to fill the other cells.

[image: Result]

Comment: @Lugizaccaria The formula works. You adding `;` instead of `,` means your system has a different regional settings than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Use =subtotal(102;b2:b11) and use the excel auto excel filter. Select "busses" in the filter.

Comment: okay, but if I want to add a new row with busses I need to change the helper column. I don't want to do that, I would like to find in the first column all the busses and then check if they have a number in the second column without having to add new instruction manualy, it shoudn't depend on the actual cell but on the column

Comment: Lugi, I can only deliver a solution based on the information you deliver.

Comment: I want to count all the cells that have busses as value in the first column and have a value in the second coloum, for example it should say 5 because we have 6 busses but only 5 have a value stored in the second column but without counting them one by one

Comment: it's not what I need because what you are doing is simply don't check the busses but I need 3 different counter at the same time. This is why I need to check if the element is busses or something else. I don't know how to do this in excel but it's something like if the (x number) of A equals busses and (x number) of B is a value, it will be counted

Comment: Lugi, you are mocking me. Each time I deliver a solution you are adding constraints. My help for you ends here.
As I said earlier:
"Lugi, I can only deliver a solution based on the information you deliver."
If you are unable to describe your problem completely neither me nor somebody else will be motivated to help you.

Comment: it's my question form the start I need to check the first colomn and the second one if all the two conditions are met it should be counted, is should be counted. Sorry if I made you think that, but I think I explained myself wrong

Comment: if you want I updated the question, if you want to give me 1 more chance it's okay but if you don't want I can understand why, in anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your wording in the description is a little confusing... "*want to count the number of cells in the right column only is they have a value in the second column*". Well, the right column IS the second column in your screenshot.

I think what you want is this, right?... You want to count the number of cells in the 2nd column that are not blank for each distinct name in the 1st column.

First create a list of distinct names from your first column. Here they are placed into column E.

Then you can use a COUNTIFS formula to achieve this.

Cell F2 formula:

```
    =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$13,E2,$B$2:$B$13,"<>"&"")
```

Drag it down, and you're done.

[image]

**EDIT**

Or just add that formula to column C and drag it down. Adjust the reference from E2 to A2.